# Differences between galvanic cells and Li-ion?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

There are clearly some differences between the classical galvanic cell and the Li-ion batteries, but if one looks at the schematics, they looks a bit similar. Please see below:

a) The galvanic cell:

[image]

and

b) Li-ion

[image: ![enter image description here]

So I know that in theory there are two fundamental differences between the galvanic cells and Li-ion batteries:

1. In LIB, the Li ions intercalate in the structure of the anode and cathode
2. In LIB, there is solid-state mass diffusion of ions.

This is easy to understand, in theory, but what happens in fact in the galvanic cell? Why isn't there any diffusion? Is it because it is not concentration driven (there are two species instead of one)? But if there is no diffusion, how are they moving? In the galvanic cell, are the ions diffusing on the surface of the electrodes instead of intercalation in the structure?

Can anyone help me to understand better the differences between the two cells?

Thank you!